# Connect to 4 different redis server createClient (without using cluster) on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, replication

I'm trying to find a way to use Redis replication. I need to connect with 4 different Redis servers without using a cluster - only replication (on node.js). The function `createClient` only connects to one Redis server, and I have 4 servers.
Is there any way to connect to all 4 of them?

Comment: Are you looking for a master-slave setup and then connect? or a sharded setup ?

Comment: @ValerianPereira I am using the Elasticache Redis. I want to use a sharded setup with nodejs. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `ioredis` package and a master-slaves setup. Here is an example

```
    const Redis = require("ioredis");

    const slaves = [
      { ip: "127.0.0.1", port: "31231", prio: 1 },
      { ip: "127.0.0.1", port: "31232", prio: 2 }
    ];

    const redis = new Redis({
      sentinels: [
        { host: "127.0.0.1", port: 26379 },
        { host: "127.0.0.1", port: 26380 }
      ],
      name: "mymaster",
      role: "slave",
      preferredSlaves: slaves
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between slaves and sentinels? Where should i write the hosts of the redis servers?

Comment: Sentinels are used for monitoring, notification and automatic failover. Slaves are basically replicas of your master server. Sentinels can promote a slave to a master if the master stops working. You can read all this in the docs it's pretty interesting